# Warning CS8032 Cannot find System.Collections.Immutable after upgrade to .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, microsoft.codeanalysis

I have a C# project (ProjectX) that I am trying to upgrade from using .NET Standard 2.0 framework to .NET 6.0. The upgrade seemingly goes smoothly and we package it into a nuget using GitLab. Now when I reference the updated package from another project (already upgraded to .NET 6.0) I get the following warning:

`Warning    CS8032  An instance of analyzer {class inheriting from Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticAnalyzer} cannot be created from ProjectX.dll: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..`

Everything I've read suggests that this is likely caused when the sdk isn't on the same version as the source generator but as far as I can tell, this not the case.

I've tried adding the Systems.Collections.Immutable package directly to ProjectX also with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I Fixed this bij downgrading 2 nugate packages in my code analyzer:
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp to 3.8.0
icrosoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces to 3.8.0